# Firefox and other apps won't start on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, firefox, 22.04, thunderbird, vnc

I'm trying to start Firefox, Thunderbird and even other apps like Geany inside a VNC server on Ubuntu 22, and they all fail with Segfaults, like the following:

```
$ firefox
libGL error: did not find extension DRI_Mesa version 1
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 8019
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
Segmentation fault
$
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use:

```
$ export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
$ firefox
```

Or

```
$ LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1 firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=i965` from `/etc/environment`.

The same thing happened to me after upgrading to Ubuntu 23.10.